# Php split echo by counting characters echoed, add variable content and then keep echoing

Tags: php, count, character, echo

In need my php code to count characters from a text being echoed. When this count gets to 64, i need it to echo "$something" and the keep echoing from where it stoped.

Also, best case scenario this code shouldn't crop complete words.

For example

-- This:

```
echo 'This is a huge string that i mean to crop acording to it\'s character\'s count. For every 64 characters including spaces i need it to echo some other thing in the middle';
```

-- Would end up like this:

```
echo 'This is a huge string that i mean to crop acording to it\'s ' . $something . 'character\'s count. For every 64 characters including spaces ' . $something . 'i need it to echo some other thing in the middle';
```

For better understanding... I need this code to solve the fact that SVG text can't be wrapped and justified.

Would you use mb_strimwidth ? how?

Thanks in advance!

--- UPDATE 1 - I've unsuccessfully tried

```
echo mb_strimwidth($row['resumen'], 0, 84, "$something");
echo mb_strimwidth($row['resumen'], 64, 64, "$something");
echo mb_strimwidth($row['resumen'], 128, 64, "$something");
```

--- UPDATE 2 - **PARTIAL SUCCESS!**

```
$uno = substr($row['resumen'], 0, 64);
$dos = substr($row['resumen'], 64, 64);
$tres = substr($row['resumen'], 128, 64);

$suma = $uno . "</text><text>" . $dos . "</text><text>" . $tres; 
echo "$suma";
```

BUT THIS JUST echoes the first line of my text.

Comment: You need to investigate output buffering. Search Google for ob_start.

Comment: I've tried with.....

echo mb_strimwidth($row['resumen'], 0, 84, "$something");
echo mb_strimwidth($row['resumen'], 64, 64, "$something");
echo mb_strimwidth($row['resumen'], 128, 64, "$something");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to this solution:

```
$n=0;

$var="Texto largo mayor a 64 caracteres que complica mi utilizacion de una infografia en svg, ya que este lenguaje no acepta wrappers para el texto. Era muy lindo para ser verdad.";

$ts= mb_strwidth($var);

//Ahora defino una variable que cuenta el texto que queda por imprimir. 
$aimprimir=mb_strwidth($var);

if ($ts>64){

    while ($aimprimir>64):
    //mientras reste por imprimir un texto de largo mayor que 64....
    echo mb_strimwidth($var,$n,70,"<br/>");
    $aimprimir=$aimprimir-64;
    $n=$n+65;
    endwhile;

    //si lo que resta por imprimir es menor o igual a 64 entonces imprimalo...
    echo mb_strimwidth($var,$n,$aimprimir,"<br/>");

}

else {

echo "$var";

}
```